# AEM6.0 Adaptive Forms as a component

Tags: aem

Has anyone successfully created an Adaptive Form as a component that can go into an AEM page?  OOTB, the form is its own page template.  Wondering if any Ninjas have accomplished this!

Answer (score 0):

So we ended up creating a container component, with a configurable path to include the Adaptive form you want on the page.

```
<div>  
    <cq:include path="${properties.path}/jcr:content/guideContainer" resourceType="fd/af/components/guideContainer"/>
</div>
```

We also created a custom form page and template styled to work within the component and subsequent page.